# Change mysql number to date format in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database the holds values for months and days as integers. For instance June 25th is (month column) 6 and (day column) 25. I have a place on a website I would like the display to be June 25th instead of 6 25. Without writing a case statement is there a way with php's built in date functions to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to do this. One example using [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
echo date("F jS", strtotime($row['month'].'/'.$row['day']));
```

Another using [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("n/j", $row['month'].'/'.$row['day']);
echo $date->format("F jS");
```

Another directly in MySQL (untested):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-',month,'-',day), "%M %D") AS the_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('l \t\h\e jS');
```

This must do